# AttributeError: 'GridSearchCV' object has no attribute 'best_params_'

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, grid-search, gridsearchcv

Grid search is a way to find the best parameters for any model out of the combinations we specify. I have formed a grid search on my model in the below manner and wish to find best parameters identified using this gridsearch.

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
# Create the parameter grid based on the results of random search 
param_grid = {
    'bootstrap': [True],'max_depth': [20,30,40, 100, 110],
    'max_features': ['sqrt'],'min_samples_leaf': [5,10,15],
    'min_samples_split': [40,50,60], 'n_estimators': [150, 200, 250]
}
# Create a based model
rf = RandomForestClassifier()
# Instantiate the grid search model
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator = rf, param_grid = param_grid, 
                          cv = 3, n_jobs = -1, verbose = 2)
```

Now I want to find the best parameters of the gridsearch as the output

```py
grid_search.best_params_
```

**Error**:

```
----> grid_search.best_params_
AttributeError: 'GridSearchCV' object has no attribute 'best_params_'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You cannot get best parameters without fitting the data.

Fit the data

```
grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Now find the best parameters.

```
grid_search.best_params_
```

`grid_search.best_params_` will work after fitting on `X_train` and `y_train`.

Answer (score 1):

If we look into [the source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/364c77e047ca08a95862becf40a04fe9d4cd2c98/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py#L899), `best_params_` is defined in the `fit()` method, so it must be called on the `GridSearchCV` or `RandomizedSearchCV` object, just as [@noob said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60786240/19123103).

If you got this error even after you fitted the data, then you probably passed multiple scoring metrics. Choose one of them to be the refitting metric and the error will go away. This is because if it's not chosen, it's not clear which metric to use to determine `best_params_`.

```py
gs = GridSearchCV(
    rf, param_grid, 
    scoring=['precision', 'recall'], refit=False,
    n_jobs=-1)
gs.fit(X_train, y_train)
gs.best_params_                                       # <---- error

gs = GridSearchCV(
    rf, param_grid, 
    scoring=['precision', 'recall'], refit='recall',
#                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   # <---- choose refit metric
    n_jobs=-1)
gs.fit(X_train, y_train)
gs.best_params_                                       # <---- OK
```

---

If you arrived here because you got the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'GridSearchCV' object has no attribute 'best_estimator_'
```

then, again, because `best_estimator_` is defined in the `fit()` method, check if you fitted the data. If you got the error even after you fitted the data, then `refit` is again the culprit. To set `best_estimator_`, `refit=True` has to hold so that the entire data can be fit again on the estimator (in the example below, Random Forest) using `best_params_`.

```py
best_ = GridSearchCV(rf, param_grid, refit=False, n_jobs=-1).fit(X_train, y_train).best_estimator_  # <---- error
best_ = GridSearchCV(rf, param_grid, refit=True, n_jobs=-1).fit(X_train, y_train).best_estimator_   # <---- OK
#                                    ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that while adapting, it was giving an error because there was line code, markdown, and line by line information.